# Can I test App in Apple store

Tags: iphone, apple-store

I found an iOS 8 bug and that bug doesn't allow me to test mediation between ads. I know it's not an issue with my code because everything works fine with iOS 7 simulators and devices and iOS 8 devices work. But on iOS 8 simulator it doesn't work. Problem is, I don't have an iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ device and don't know anyone who does. The test of device takes about 10 minutes and has no negative affects on device.

Would I be allowed to hook up my Apple MacBook to the iPhone 6 in the Apple Store to test my app?

Answer (score 1):

I would reach out to the business team in that store and explain your dilemma.

You wouldn't want to monkey with one of the display phones as they are likely under surveillance and you might not be able to reset them properly.

Most stores have an unlocked phone for the support staff to test things, so if you made an appointment towards the close of business, perhaps they would indulge your request. Also, look for a local cocoa heads or developer group. Someone might be willing to swap testing with you. Also, stack overflow iOS developer group might be a good place to ask for an assist.

Answer (score 0):

Try asking in Stackexchange sites for programmers and application development. Examples of sites that I found on the All StackExchange sites list is: Code Review or Programers.
Maybe they want and have the possibility to try out your app on an iPhone 6 or iPhone 6+.